# Why looping through array gives non existent value?

Tags: arrays, c, loops

I have 2 multidimensional arrays filled with x and y coordinates. Im comparing both arrays to find a match in nested loop like this

```
int order;
order = 0;
float c[4][2];
for (int i = 0;i <= sizeofarrB; i++ ) {
   for (int j = 0;j <= sizeofarrA; j++ ) {
        if (a[j][0] == b[i][0] && a[j][1] == b[i][1]){
        printf("testx = %f y = %f\n " , a[j][0], a[j][1]);
        printf("testx = %f y = %f\n", b[i][0], b[i][1]);
            c[order][0] = b[i][0];
            c[order][1] = b[i][1];
            order++;
        }

   }
}
```

[image: first array]

these are values of first array

[image: second array]

these are values of second array

and these are the values that i get from running that nested loop
[image: final values]

i have no idea how to fix the code to get correct values

Comment: You probably need `<` instead of `<=` in the loop controls. An array is indexed from `0` to 'length-1'.

Comment: What are sizeofarrA and sizeofarrB? Needs a [mcve], not a fragment of code.

Comment: Also `float c[4][2];` should be `float c[sizeofarrA * sizeofarrB][2]` but its size is hard coded with `4`. Or `order = (order + 1) % 4;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `i <= sizeofarrB` as a loop condition, but you should use `i < sizeofarrB`, as an array of size 4 will have indices from 0 to 3.

You are reading out of the memory area that belongs to the array, a typical way of corrupting memory in C.

Comment: damn im stupid, thanks.. my logic behind it was that im declaring array as float a[sizeofarrA][2];
float b[sizeofarrB][2]; so to get through the whole array it has to be <= but its indexed from 0... sorry for wasting everybodys time with this stupid question

Comment: @kpcttobee mark as correct answer then :) I'm glad it helped.